# Is there a way to access one database from another in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have recently switched from MySQL to Postgres and am still is discovery mode.

In MySQL I could be connected to `radius_db` and still run a query against `main_db`.

However in Postgresql this doesn't seem possible.

```
radius_db=# SELECT COALESCE((SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expires_at) FROM main_db.device d WHERE d.id='123'), 0);
ERROR:  relation "main_db.device" does not exist
LINE 1: ... COALESCE((SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expires_at) FROM main_db.de...
                                                             ^
radius_db=#
```

Both `radius_db` and `main_db` belong to the same Schema (public). Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: What MySQL calls a "database" is actually a schema. So you probably want to use schemas in Postgres in a single database

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is an interesting idea. I could put each "database" into a separate schema. How do I access each in this case? `select * from schema2.main_db.device`? Sadly the question is already closed. (I don't want to use Foreign data wrapper)

Comment: `select * from schema2.device`  - note that you have the hierarchy wrong (at least the way you wrote it in the question). A database contains multiple schema. So "main_db belongs to schema public" makes no sense.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I'll give it a shot and may come back with a new question. :-)